# I get a segmentation fault on this code at a different line every time. C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, genetic-algorithm

I am writing a genetic algorithm program. I use Linux (OS), c++ (language) and g++ (compiler).
The following code generates a seg fault. The problem is that it sometimes run 50+ times and some times none. Plus the error occurs in any of the tmp[ k ][ p ] or tmp[ k + 1 ][ p ] assignment lines. Am I missing something here?

```
int** GeneticAlgorythm::newGeneration( int** parents )
{
    int** tmp = new int*[ population ];
    int p = 0;

    for( int k = 0; k < population; k += 2 )
    {
        tmp[ k ] = new int[ nGenes ];
        tmp[ k + 1 ] = new int[ nGenes ];
        setLikelihood( parents );

        int parent1 = getParent( likelyhood );
        int parent2 = getParent( likelyhood );

        while( parent1 == parent2 )
        {
            parent2 = getParent( likelyhood );
        }

        for( p = 0; p < crossOverPoint; p++ )
        {
            tmp[ k ][ p ] = parents[ parent1 ][ p ];
            tmp[ k + 1 ][ p ] = parents[ parent2 ][ p ];
        }

        for( p = crossOverPoint; p < nGenes; p++ )
        {
            tmp[ k ][ p ] = parents[ parent2 ][ p ];
            tmp[ k + 1 ][ p ] = parents[ parent1 ][ p ];
        }
    }

    currGeneration++;
    return tmp;
}


int GeneticAlgorythm::getParent( double* lh )
{
    int randVal = rand( ) % 100;
    int* choose = new int[ 100 ];
    int counter = 0;

    for( int k = 0; k < population; k++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < (int)likelyhood[ k ]; j++ )
        {
            choose[ counter++ ] = j;
        }
    }

    counter = choose[ randVal ];
    delete[] choose;
    return counter;
}

void GeneticAlgorythm::setLikelihood( int** pg )
{
    multipleInverse = 0;
    double one = 1.00;

    for( int mi = 0; mi < population; mi++ )
    {
        multipleInverse  += one/checkFitness( pg[ mi ] );

    }

    for( int lh = 0; lh < population; lh++ )
    {
        likelyhood[ lh ] = round(((one/checkFitness( pg[ lh ] ))/multipleInverse) * 100);
    }

}
```

**Variable values:**
population = 20; nGenes = 3; crossOverPoint = 1;

likelihood is how likely a parent is to be selected based on their fitness level.
pg is the parent genes. [ population ][ nGenes ].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `setLikelihood()` do?

Comment: What are the dimensions of `parents`?  Is `getParent(…)` guaranteed to return a valid index?

Comment: setLikelihood() gives each parent a likelihood ( in percentage) to be chosen as a parent. The better the fitness, the better the likelihood

Comment: do an `assert(p < nGenes);`

Also, you need to know if the error happens with `tmp[ k ][ p ]` or with  `parents[ parent1 ][ p ]`.  So do this:  `int tmpint=parents[parent1][p]; tmp[k][p]=tmpint;`

In fact, with so many potential segfaults here, you should pepper this function with assert statements.  Think about all of the assumptions you are making.  `assert(parents!=NULL);` and `assert(population%2==0);` and  `assert(parents[parent1]!=NULL);` just to start

Comment: @HalCanary I am  not familiar with assert? But there is conditions in the program else where to make sure all these variables and pointers do in fact have values.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the values that you provided, it looks like your indexing into `tmp` is OK.  If the lines where you're seeing the segfault are

```
tmp[ k ][ p ] = parents[ parent1 ][ p ];
tmp[ k + 1 ][ p ] = parents[ parent2 ][ p ];
```

it would have to be because of the indexing into `parents` with `[ parentN ][ p ]`.
What are the dimensions of `parents`? Is `getParent(…)` guaranteed to return a valid index into `parents`?

Comment: +1 That can be the cause of the error too. You should be doing boundary checks if you can't guarantee the return value of getParent will be within bounds.

Comment: parents is a int** the size: parents[ population ][ nGenes ]. getParents only returns an int for which parent to use.

Comment: @Ravenblack Probably the `tmp` from a previous interation, eh?  OK then, how do `setLikelihood` and `getParent` work?  It seems like `getParent` must be giving you a bad index.  Can you post code for them?  Perhaps `getParent` is returning something in the range [1,population] rather than [0,population-1].

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I added it to the question.

Comment: @Ravenblack Thanks for adding it.  I have to run at the moment, so I can't decipher `getParent` at the moment, but the advice that you're getting the question comments are sound.  Check that `parentN` is less than population, and that `p` is less than `nGenes`, either by an assertion, or printing it out and looking at it, or … .  It shouldn't take long to figure out which index is not in the range that you expect it to be, especially since you know what all the ranges should be.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I appreciate it. I will check those indexes.

Comment: @Ravenblack Did you ever get this resolved?  Did those indices check out?

Answer (score 2):

Your `tmp[k+1]` can go out of bounds. Assume `population` = 3. On your second loop run you got `i=2` and you do `tmp[i+1]` which is tmp[3] and that is out of bounds which can cause undefined behavior because you're modifying memory outside your buffer space.

Unless you are sure that `population` is *always* an even number.

Comment: @Sarien you're right, I didn't notice the variable values given. OP, Are you always trying with population=20? I don't see what else can go bad.

Comment: Well for now its 20, until I get the problem sorted out. But I'll definitely look at that uneven values. And I don't know why it gives a seg fault, according to me that code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
int** tmp = new int* [population];

for (int k = 0; k < population; k += 2)
{
    tmp[k] = new int[nGenes];
    tmp[k + 1] = new int[nGenes];
    ...
}
```

when `population` is odd number, `tmp[k + 1]` within the last iteration access the array out of its bounds, which produces ***undefined behavior***. You were lucky enough to observe the crash of your program due to segmentation fault, otherwise this bug might have stayed hidden.

Comment: Another user pointed this out too, but OP clarified that it's even in this case.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Would be nice to see `getParent` and `setLikelihood` functions though.

Comment: @LihO I added those functions to the question